# How to test .NET Standard AND Core versions of a library properly?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, nunit, .net-standard

**Background:**

I have a library, which targets both .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Core (among others). Since .NET Standard 2.0 lacks many features that are present in .NET Core/Framework I throw `PlatformNotSupportedException` from many members in the .NET Standard 2.0 version.

**Issue 1:**

A UnitTest project cannot target .NET Standard so in the test project I use .NET Core 2.0 both for the .NET Core and Standard versions.

In the library .csproj I need to change the targets manually:

```xml
library.csproj:
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Compiles everything; for testing everything but .NET Standard 2.0 -->
  <TargetFrameworks>net35;net40;net45;netcoreapp2.0;netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>
  <!-- For testing .NET Standard 2.0: -->
  <!--<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>-->
</PropertyGroup>

test.csproj:
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- now 'netcoreapp2.0' references either the .NET Core 2.0 or Standard 2.0 version depending on library.csproj -->
  <TargetFrameworks>net35;net40;net45;netcoreapp2.0;netcoreapp3.0</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\library\library.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Issue 2:**

Considering that a unit test project cannot target .NET Standard this code does not work:

```cs
[Test]
public void TestSomethingThatIsNotAvailableInNetStandard20()
{
    TestDelegate testCode = () => ...;

#if NETSTANDARD2_0 // This is never true
    Assert.Throws<PlatformNotSupportedException>(testCode);
#else
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(testCode);
#endif
}
```

Instead, now I use something like this:

```cs
[Test]
public void TestSomethingThatIsNotAvailableInNetStandard20()
{
    TestDelegate testCode = () => ...;

#if NETCOREAPP2_0 // .NET Core 2.0 OR .NET Standard 2.0
    if (IsNetStandard20)
        Assert.Throws<PlatformNotSupportedException>(testCode);
    else
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(testCode);
#else // all other targets
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(testCode);
#endif
}

...

// yikes... :/
public static bool IsNetStandard20 => typeof(SomeTypeFromMyLib).Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
    .Any(an => an.Name == "netstandard" && an.Version == new Version(2, 0, 0, 0));
```

**The Question:**

Is there a way to test the .NET Standard 2.0 version without changing the .csproj file all the time (and to get rid of the `IsNetStandard20` property if possible)?

**Disclaimer:**

I know that normally it would be enough to ship a .NET Standard 2.0 version to support .NET Core apps but unfortunately it has many missing features that .NET Core 2.0 has (which are included in .NET Standard 2.1 though, so there is no need for a separate .NET Core 3.0 version).

Comment: Unless someone can elaborate on how to achieve what you are looking for another way, please accept my answer. Afaik there is no other way today to solve your problem.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but it does not solve my problem. It seems "there is no way" is more correct than "no other way".

Answer (score 1):

> A UnitTest project cannot target .NET Standard so in the test project I use .NET Core 2.0 both for the .NET Core and Standard versions.

This statement is not *entirely* correct. Unit test projects can target .NETStandard but most test platforms can't find or execute these tests.

Code targeting .NETCore can be *explicitly* tested in a .NETCore process.
Code targeting .NETStandard on the other hand can only be *implicitly* tested in processes using runtimes that implement the specified version of .NETStandard.
If you want to test the latter you need to run your tests on all *matching runtimes* that you expect to see usage on with consumers of your library.

If you want to have your unit test project to target .NETStandard then you should look at [Nuclear.Test](https://mikelimasierra.net/index.php/software-projects/nuclear-test-platform/).
This allows you to build your unit tests against .NETStandard and have them execute on versions of .NETCore *and* .NETFramework that implement your .NETStandard version of choice.

You can target your unit test project at .NETStandard 2.0 and .NETCoreApp 2.0 the way you already do.
Your tests will very much look like your first example.

```cs
[TestMethod]
void TestSomethingThatIsNotAvailableInNetStandard20()
{
    TestDelegate testCode = () => ...;

#if NETSTANDARD2_0 // This is compiled into net standard test assembly
    Test.If.ThrowsException(testCode, out PlatformNotSupportedException ex);
    // Assert.Throws<PlatformNotSupportedException>(testCode);
#else // This is compiled into every other test assembly
    Test.IfNot.ThrowsException(testCode, out PlatformNotSupportedException ex);
    // Assert.DoesNotThrow(testCode);
#endif
}
```

This approach will solve your problem as described.
However it might introduce new problems due to a change of the unit testing platform.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This NuclearTest looks promising because it proves that the issue could be fundamentally handled after all. Unfortunately I could not migrate to it as it has significantly different API and features than NUnit has. I upvoted you though. Nice project, grats.

Comment: Thank you. I'm hoping that this way of executing test assemblies will make it into vsts some day so that we'll all get to write tests in .NETStandard.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation (and for the same reasons as [György Kőszeg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5114784/gy%c3%b6rgy-k%c5%91szeg) pointed out), I had a multi targeting C# library project with the following entry in the csproj:

```
<!-- All target frameworks go into the NuGet package -->
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1;net461</TargetFrameworks>
```

For the test project I finally came up with:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net462;netcoreapp3.1;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>

<!-- Project reference for netstandard2.1 and net462 -->
<!-- net5.0 will test the netstandard2.1 assembly -->
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' != 'netcoreapp3.1'">
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Path-To\ProjectToTest.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Add test configuration for netstandard2.0 assemblies -->
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp3.1'">
    <Reference Include="ProjectToTest">
        <HintPath>..\ProjectToTest\bin\$(Configuration)\netstandard2.0\ProjectToTest.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <!-- Include all package references of the netstandard2.0 assembly -->
    <PackageReference Include="System.Memory" Version="4.5.4" />
</ItemGroup>
```

As you see in the JetBrains dotCover report, this seems to work.
[image: JetBrains dotCover report]

Not sure, whether this is the only (or even the best) way to get tests run for both netstandard2.0 **and** netstandard2.1. The hard coded references are not good to maintain, but it's more reliable than changing the csproj manually for each test run.